# action bar is hiding the upper edit text and text view

Tags: android, xml

The action bar in my application is hiding the upper edit text and text view. I don't know how to go around this issue. I have pasted the xml layout code below.
I want to show some menu items in the action bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"         
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: dear i am new to this site and don't know how to post code as it's showing errors while posting

Comment: hey Jack i have posted the code.

Comment: First text view is invisible or overlapped by Toolbar?

Comment: so how could i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That design seems to be wrong.and i think the problem is in the:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Which you set it for `GridLayout` and it should hide that or causes problem.So, use the `Layout` like this and make sure you are not using it inside `NestedScrollView` because you already have `ScrollView`: (better to use `NestedScrollView` instead `ScrollView` which seems you are using `CoordinatorLayout`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="40">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="CODE" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="NAME" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:text="PHONE" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:text="ADDRESS" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:text="E-MAIL" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:text="REG.NO." />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:text="REG.DATE" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="12"
            android:text="SAVE ME" />

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MainLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Also, i'd rather to use `NestedScrollView` instead like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Contents:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="50"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:rowCount="40"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="CODE" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:text="NAME" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:text="PHONE" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:text="ADDRESS" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:text="E-MAIL" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:text="REG.NO." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:text="REG.DATE" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:text="SAVE ME" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: result is still the same. it's not showing first textview and edit text

Comment: Can i see your `MainLayout` codes? Please paste it somewhere or add it in the question.

Comment: sure i am adding it to the main question wait

Comment: i have added the main activity xml layout code in the main question.  I am Using the code pasted by you, but the problem is same. Please look into the main activity code and suggest me some solution. That would be of great help to me.

Comment: It's working, Please see if i am missing something: http://i.imgur.com/PPgUpwB.png also, delete those : `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"` from that include, i just add and updated it in the answer.

Comment: @user2468471 - Glad to hear, please consider that to accept the answer too.